# What is the purpose of REQUIRESCRIPT and below lines

Tags: community

What is the purpose of the below lines

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection.js imports global variables and functions required to get the session ID , execute soql, login ,describe metadata and various other functions and utilities  to work with  salesforce data and metadata from the client side JavaScript .

You can find more details here in the Ajax toolkit guide.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_connecting.htm

And apex.js allows you to call apex methods using client side JavaScript .These do not work in lightning experience .Ajax toolkit was used in buttons in classic experience to make Ajax call to Salesforce without refreshing the standard page .